# iOS status bar overlapping contents

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ios-statusbar

I have built phonegap application, it works fine on android and windows. 
But for iOS I am facing issue as, status bar contents and page contents are mixed up therefore i unable to tap on the back button provided in header.
Can any body help me about this..?

This is my config.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"

        id        = "io.example.com"
        version     = "1.0.2">
    <name>MyAPP</name>

    <description>

    </description>

    <author  email="rakesh@gmail.com">
        Rakesh
    </author>

    <access origin="*"/>


    <content src="index.html" />


    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />   <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <!-- <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />  -->          <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />        <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="7" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />

    <icon src="icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="icon-120.png"           gap:platform="ios"        width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="icon-76.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="icon-76-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="152" height="152" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:splash src="SplashScreenImage.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
    <gap:splash src="screen-iphone-portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
    <string>100</string>
    </gap:config-file>

    <feature name="App">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>

    <!-- Deprecated plugins element. Remove in 3.0 -->


</widget>
```

Comment: plz share your config.xml

Comment: please share some code content for better understanding of your bug.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add these lines to your config.xml file

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
        <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
        <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
      <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" />
```

Answer (score 28):

The accepted answer from sunil is no longer relevant, the plugin is deprecated.

Use the following in your config.xml

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
<plugin spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git" source="git" />
```

Comment: good explanation of this here: http://devgirl.org/2014/07/31/phonegap-developers-guid/

Comment: This created a clean well-spaced statusbar with black background and white font color that separated the app from the bar. Perfect for my app, thanks~

Comment: Its not working even though i did the same as you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished with the help of the [statusbar plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git).
All you need is to install the plugin via the command line `phonegap plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git` and then add `StatusBar.hide();` onDeviceReady event.

Comment: Question was not to hide the element. It just shouldn't overlap the content.

Answer (score 4):

For detail usage in codova 6+ now, for more of @sunil's solution, we should use

```
cordova plugins add -save cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

For detail usage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide the StatusBar totaly you can add two keys into your `info.plist` which are Booleans:

```
Status bar is initially hidden - YES

View controller-based status bar appearance - NO
```

Answer (score 3):

Applied @sunil resolution but,

My problem was of "Content Security Policy" on iOS 10

Added below line to index.html resolved the issue:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' gap://ready file://* *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Answer (score 0):

add these lines in `config.xml` use this it will fix your issue and status bar will appear:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true"/>

<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000"/>

<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "these lines"?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21516218)

Comment: In Hybrid application there is the config file, in which we have to make some entries for displaying the status bar in proper manner

Comment: Didn’t work for me.